# How to close write handle of anynomous pipe

Tags: c++, windows, pipe

i createprocess to run system command, so that it can output all the time. But, i want to break it when some commands spend too much time ,such as 1min.
I used to closehandle of pipe, but it cannot work. ReadFile still hang , i don't know how to deal with it .

I was wondering if I can insert some data, readfile will exit while reading this data, or other solutions.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

std::string run(const wchar_t* pszCmd)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = { sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES), NULL, TRUE };
    HANDLE hRead, hWrite;
    if (!CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &sa, 0))
    {
        return "";
    }


    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(STARTUPINFO) };
    GetStartupInfo(&si);
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;
    si.hStdError = hWrite;
    si.hStdOutput = hWrite;
 
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (!CreateProcessW(L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", (LPWSTR)pszCmd, NULL, NULL, TRUE, NULL, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        DWORD err_code = GetLastError();
        return "e";
    }

    CloseHandle(hWrite);

    std::string strRet = "";
    char buff[1024] = { 0 };
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    
    while (ReadFile(hRead, buff, 1024, &dwRead, NULL))
    {
        strRet.append(buff, dwRead);
    }
    CloseHandle(hRead);

    return strRet;
}

int main()
{
    std::wstring cmd = L"/c  ping 8.8.8.8 -t ";
    std::string res = run(cmd.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

I tried another function, createthread to run this function ,and break thread after a timeout, but i cannot find how to to this.

Any solution can deal with this problem, thanks very much

Comment: `ReadFile` is synchronous so it's most likely waiting for data from your pipe

Comment: I'd read the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/anonymous-pipe-operations) for this.  I'm unsure if the way you're passing the handles to your child process is correct.  That doc specifically says "The ReadFile call can also return if all write handles to the pipe have been closed or if an error occurs before the read operation has been completed."  If that's not happening, that suggests that DuplicateHandle may have been called, so all write handles are *not* closed yet.  Investigate that angle.

Comment: @Kevin Anderson, yes ,I thought of that possibility, too. maybe ping program DuplicateHandle, but i don't know how to close it in parent process

Comment: @zzz999 I would think about this differently if I were you.  If you pass a handle to a child process, you can't then "close it in parent process" and expect success.  Consider the resource "gone".  Work on how to do what you want from the parent through other mechanisms, like `ReadFileEx` that allows timeouts, and signal the child process (through other events) to close the handle itself.  You need either a re-think, or a better expert with Windows pipes, or maybe both!